# Close a MessageDialog Programmaticaly in WinUI3

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, dialog, winui

I've ported my app from .NET Core to WinUI .NET5 and now my message dialogs dont desapear when a button is clicked. How can I solve that?

Comment: I am unable to find documentation for hiding it, but you could try converting it into a ContentDialog instead if that isn't a problem: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/winui/api/microsoft.ui.xaml.controls.contentdialog?view=winui-3.0, that one has a Hide() function to be used programmatically.

Comment: It has but i doesn't workm I've already tried that